# Connect Bluetooth Devices using IOBluetooth for Mac Os x

Tags: macos, core-bluetooth, iobluetooth

I am creating Os x Application on Mavericks with Xcode 6. I want to do simple task in this Application like search for Bluetooth Devices and display List, Connect with device which is selected from list.

I am using IOBluetooth Framework. I have completed searching, display and selection part but I am not able to connect with device.

I have write

```
IOBluetoothDevice *device= [[IOBluetoothDevice alloc] init];
IOReturn status=[device openConnection:[self.list objectAtIndex:row]];
if(status == kIOReturnSuccess){ 
    NSLog(@"Device Connect Successfully::::");
}
```

"Device Connect Successfully" Message printed on console but device is still not connected.

So I am following right way to connect device? If Device is Connected then how do I Check it is connected or not?

Comment: This method is asynchronous - you need to wait for the callback to know that the device is connected - "If a target is specified, the open connection call is asynchronous and on completion of the CREATE_CONNECTION command, the method -connectionComplete:status: will be called on the specified target."  Are you working with "legacy" Bluetooth devices or BLE?  If BLE then CBCentralManager is a better class to use than IOBluetooth

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have successfully connected device using IOBluetooth. I am passing Peripheral as parameter for OpenConnection instead of that I have to pass IOBluetoothDevice Object.  I have tried with CBCentralManager But its not worked so I have found alternative way IOBluetooth. Anyway Thank you so much for your reply.